# How can I simplify this regex?

Tags: java, regex

Here is a rather complex regex:

```
^\s*(?:\d{2}|\d{2}\s*\d{2}|\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}|\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}|\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2})\s*$
```

Graphically, it becomes:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

How can it be reduced?

I have tried positive lookaheads with no success (`(?=\d{4})[\s\d]+` for example).

#### Requirements

The regex:

- Allows from one to five pairs of numbers.
- Allows zero or more blank characters between pairs of numbers.

Here is a set of valid inputs the regex must match: https://regex101.com/r/hN0pT4/7

### Example

```
// OK                  // NOK
12                     123
1234                   12 345
123456                 123 45 45
12345678               1 2 3 4 5
1234567890             12 34 56 78 90 11
12 34
12 3456
12 34 56 78
12 34 567890
```

**EDIT**
Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361240/363573

Comment: What's the rule here ? Rule to match those numbers. What pattern are you trying to match. I can see those sample inputs but they don't say much about rule to match. Regex is long and complicated to comprehend. So explaining the rule will be much better.

Comment: @noob What is *"the rule"* for you?

Comment: Does `^\s*\d{2}(\s*\d{2}){0,4}\s*$` work?

Comment: What about just `^(\d{2} ?)*$`?

Comment: `\d{2}(\s*\d{2})*`  ?

Comment: @Tunaki It would be possible to enter 12 or more digits.

Comment: @khelwood  It would be possible to enter 12 or more digits.

Comment: @Stephan So then `\d{2}(\s*\d{2}){0,4}`  ?

Comment: Well then `^(\d{2} ?){1,5}$`?

Comment: I think you mean "zero or more blank characters"

Comment: `^((\d{2}\s*)*)$` Check :- https://regex101.com/r/hN0pT4/4

Comment: @rock321987 It would be possible to enter 12 or more digits.

Comment: I have written an answer

Comment: @noob, You are freaking us out. I'll flag you. You cannot change the requirements of the OP!

Comment: @anubhava: Like this `12 34 56 23 45 3456`. It's not said that there shouldn't be more digits. But **five pairs must be present.**

Comment: @noob: Are you the OP? no

Comment: @enrico.bacis: **You have neglected OP's requirement in comments to suit your answer.**

Comment: @anubhava: Yes, there should be atleast five pairs. But there could be more digits too.

Comment: noob: the question was asked by the user @Stephan, not by you. There are requirements, there are examples. You are the only one that misunderstood the question here. stop here or I will seriously call a mod.

Comment: @enrico.bacis: Nothing against your Sir. Your solution is straight forward and simple anyone with basic Regex understanding could come up with. But you are neglecting the basic fact here.

Comment: @anubhava: Please check above comments where OP mentioned that **It would be possible to enter 12 or more digits.**

Comment: @noob: You are misunderstanding the OP's comments.

Comment: @Welbog: In that case we should wait for OP to clarify more details. Which I mentioned in the very first comment.

Comment: @noob: I stop here. Asked for moderation attention. Bye

Comment: @enrico.bacis: I don't see what you expect a moderator to do in this situation. Stephan can mark an answer as accepted and then we'll know the actual requirements.

Comment: @Stephan: Could you please clarify on this **It would be possible to enter 12 or more digits** issue ?

Comment: @noob I wrote this to guys who have posted regexes allowing more than 5 pairs of digits. The regex mustn't allow more than 5 pairs. Sorry if I was unclear.

Comment: Here is the final solution I chose: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36361240/363573

Comment: @noob enrico is correct. You should not inject your opinion into the question without first getting clarification from OP. Your edit changed the question enough to invalidate answers. In future, ask OP via comments to clarify requirements before editing the question yourself, and only edit if you believe the question *needs* editing.

Comment: @Welbog: now that the case is closed I can reply: I asked for moderator attention because the behaviour and attitude of the user "noob" seriously mine the foundation of collaboration and cooperation this place is founded on. We were cooperative and he was freaking out, injecting wrong understanding in the OP's post. This is unacceptable and requires moderator attention. Case closed, thanks to everyone who contributed in a cooperative way.

Comment: @enrico.bacis: It would be right to mention that I suggest you to take a look at the comment and you sir freaked out.

Comment: @Bohemian: Yes I did asked OP to clarify question. And only when I saw OP mention the same thing thrice I edited the question. There was no intention to **invalidate** any user's answer as it would not get me anything and I also intend no harm. Apologies if a user felt offended by my suggestion to **read comments properly**.

Comment: @noob: Just to conclude: the flag against you resulted "helpful", this means that also the moderators agreed that your behaviour was not right. We were not pissed by you asking to read comments but by the fact that you edited the question injecting what, at the end, resulted your (and your only) wrong interpretation. You seem an hardworking member of this community, but please try to improve your manners from this experience. Peace

Comment: @enrico.bacis: Same happened for flag against you. What do you say now ?

Comment: @noob: that it is fair. It is also my fault if the comments section of this question has this size. By the way, at the end of the day, I was right and you were wrong, so next time think before starting a flame war. I ask the mods to clean up here, we are done. Have a nice day

Comment: @enrico bacis: Still adamant on proving right and wrong. That says it all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shortest/simplest is:

```
^ *(\d\d *){1,5}$
```

Notes:

- `\d\d` (4 chars) is shorter/simpler than `\d{2}` (5 chars, with quantifier)
- space char (1 char) is simpler then `\s` (2 chars)
- you don't need the trailing `\s*` because any trailing spaces are consumed by the inner expression

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/t5lyMnpFd4) passing all your posted test cases.

If you really need to allow other whitespace chars (eg tabs), then use:

```
^\s*(\d\d\s*){1,5}$
```

Comment: Really simple solution here. IMO, with non capturing parentheses it is even simpler.

Comment: @stephan I thought about using a non-capturing group, which is simpler for the regex engine, but more complex for the programmer. I interpreted "simpler" as "simpler for the programmer". It's a good point though.

Answer (score 7):

What about the literal translation of:

> pairs of numbers (max 5 pairs) with zero or more spaces between

that is:

```
^\s*(\d{2}\s*){1,5}\s*$
```

You can see a demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/aD5oU6/3).

Comment: Change that `\s?` to `\s*` and you match the same stuff as the original expression.

Comment: Also, "one or more spaces" would be `\s+` not `\s?`. I think `\s?` what OP wants though

Comment: As OP specified in a comment it should be able to allow more than 12 digits. this fails to match `12 34 56 23 45 3456` Which has 5 pairs and more than 12 digits.

Comment: @noob: I don't get it. This is not in the OP's requirements.

Comment: @enrico.bacis: Read the comments. OP should mention that in question. That's why I talked about rules in the very first comment.

Comment: @noob: I believe the OP is saying that with rock321987's solution, it *would* be possible to enter more than the allowed characters. BTW the requirements are there. If the requirements change, the OP should change them, or even better, post another question in order not to mess here.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best I could produce

```
^(\d{2} ?){1,5}$

^\s*(\d{2} *){1,5}\s*$   <--- forgot the whitespaces 0 to n times (edit)
```

### Expl :

`^` : Begin of string

`(\d{2} ?)` : Matches pairs of digits with an optional

`{1,5}` : The group can be repeated one to five times (5 pairs max)

`$` : End of string

---

### [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hN0pT4/5)

Comment: Zero or more blank spaces. I made a mistake initially, sorry.

Comment: Zero or more blank spaces *after* the digits.

Answer (score 2):

Let's break it down:

- `^\s*(?:x)\s*$` is easy enough: start of the input, any whitespace, group x, any whitespace, end - not much to simplyfy here.
- now group x: `\d{2}|\d{2}\s*\d{2}|\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}|\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}|\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}`
  If you split it at the pipes (i.e. "or"-operators) you get this:

  - `\d{2}`
  - `\d{2}\s*\d{2}`
  - `\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}`
  - `\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}`
  - `\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}\s*\d{2}`

See a pattern? They all start with `\d{2}` and each time there is one more `\s*\d{2}` - up to 4 times. So this can be simplified to `\d{2}(?:\s*\d{2}){0,4}`

Putting it together you get `^\s*(?:\d{2}(?:\s*\d{2}){0,4})\s*$`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

```
^\s*((?:\d{2}\s*){1,5})$
```

Explanation as per comment (*Regex Breakdown*)

```
^ #Starting of string
 \s* #Consume any spaces from starting
 (    #Capturing group to capture the whole string if it matches the below requirements (It is not necessary to use it if you are only matching the string)
   (?:\d{2}\s*){1,5} #Non capturing group to check the pattern
 )
$ #End of string
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/hN0pT4/6)**

Comment: Why do you use capturing parentheses ate the beginning?

Comment: I have added an explanation. I think it was `at` and not `ate` in your comment

Answer (score 0):

Here's yet another way:

```
(\d\s*\d\s*){1,5}
```

Correctly matches all of the OP's examples:

match       12 
match       1234
match       123456
match       12345678
match       1234567890
match       12 34
match       12 3456
match       12 34 56 78
match       12 34 567890
no match    123
no match    12 345
no match    123 45 45
no match    1 2 3 4 5

Comment: @rock321987 no it won't.

Comment: @Stephan I noticed in that link the "flavor" of regex is set to PHP, maybe slightly different behaviour compared to Java.

Comment: @AdamRice regex101 doesn't support Java yet. Often PCRE (php) has a close behavior with Java regex flavor.

Comment: The output here was taken from a Java app so probably more accurate in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, pattern repeat is required. You could try:

```
^(\s*\d{2}(?:[^\S\n]*\d{2}){0,4}\s*)$
```

[**REGEX 101 DEMO**](https://regex101.com/r/nW1vD0/1)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the final solution I have selected:

```
^(?:\s*\d{2}){1,5}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Thank you all guys !